# updating scala version to 2.10.0 in lift app

Tags: java, scala, lift

I am working with the sample Lift framework, downloaded from github.com. Scala 2.9.1 is the version in it. I am using Container:start command in cmd for starting the server and I can see the app in localhost:8080. But I have installed scala 2.10.0 in Eclipse. If I integrate the project with the Eclipse IDE the localhost:8080 showing some errors. What is the problem?

I have the `build.sbt` with:

```
name := "Lift 2.5 starter template"

version := "0.0.1"

organization := "net.liftweb"

scalaVersion := "2.9.1"

resolvers ++= Seq("snapshots"     at      "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
            "releases"        at "http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases"
            )

seq(com.github.siasia.WebPlugin.webSettings :_*)

unmanagedResourceDirectories in Test <+= (baseDirectory) { _ / "src/main/webapp" }

scalacOptions ++= Seq("-deprecation", "-unchecked")

libraryDependencies ++= {
  val liftVersion = "2.5-RC2"
  Seq(
    "net.liftweb"       %% "lift-webkit"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
    "net.liftweb"       %% "lift-mapper"        % liftVersion        % "compile",
    "net.liftmodules"   %% "lift-jquery-module" % (liftVersion + "-2.2"),
    "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp"        % "8.1.7.v20120910"  % "container,test",
    "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container,test"  artifacts Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar"),
    "ch.qos.logback"    % "logback-classic"     % "1.0.6",
    "org.specs2"        %% "specs2"             % "1.12.1"           % "test",
    "com.h2database"    % "h2"                  % "1.3.167"
  )
}
```

I have integrated with Eclipse in projects/plugins.sbt

```
 addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To update Eclipse you need to update ScalaIDE plugin to work with 2.10.**
http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e37/scala210/dev/site/

If your `build.sbt` or `plugin.sbt` containts a line saying:

```
scalaVersion := "2.10.0"
```

SBT will find the line, interpret it, and automatically download the 2.10 Scala Compiler and 2.10 Scala library for the typesafe repo. This is found in the typesafe resolver, which is usually added as a global resolver in `~/.sbt/`, like this `resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver`.

If you will compile the project with a `scalaVersion := "2.10.0"` line inside the build definition(same goes for a plugin) and you don't have Scala 2.10 installed or in your path, then SBT will download it automatically from the typesafe resolver and place the downloaded files in
`~/.sbt/boot/scala-2.10.0/lib/`, where you will find the following files:

```
jansi.jar, jline.jar, scala-compiler.jar, scala-library.jar, scala-reflect.jar
```

Here is sample `build.sbt` config for lift 2.5M3 application originally created with Scala 2.9.2, upgraded to 2.10.

```
name := "secret"

version := "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

scalaVersion := "2.10.0"

seq(com.github.siasia.WebPlugin.webSettings :_*)

seq(jrebelSettings: _*)

jrebel.webLinks <++= webappResources in Compile

resolvers ++= Seq(
    "Sonatype OSS Snapshots" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots",
    "Sonatype releases" at "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases",
    "Scala 2.10 support for rogue" at "https://github.com/mattpap/rogue/"
)

libraryDependencies ++= {
    val liftVersion = "2.5-M4"
    Seq(
      "com.foursquare" %% "rogue-field" % "2.0.0-beta22",
      "com.foursquare" %% "rogue-core" % "2.0.0-beta22",
      "com.foursquare" %% "rogue-lift" % "2.0.0-beta22",
      "net.liftweb" %% "lift-webkit" % liftVersion % "compile",
      "net.liftweb"    %% "lift-mongodb-record" % "2.5-M4",
      "com.mongodb.casbah" % "casbah_2.9.0" % "2.2.0-SNAPSHOT",
      "org.specs2" %% "specs2" % "1.12.3" % "test"
     )
}

classpathTypes ~= (_ + "orbit")

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty.orbit" % "javax.servlet" % "3.0.0.v201112011016" % "container" artifacts (Artifact("javax.servlet", "jar", "jar")
  )
)

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.eclipse.jetty" % "jetty-webapp" % "8.1.7.v20120910" % "container" artifacts (Artifact("jetty-webapp", "jar", "jar")
  )
) 

port in container.Configuration := 5555

EclipseKeys.withSource := true
```

**Here is the plugins.sbt file, which should be in PROJECTROOT/project/plugins.sbt**

```
libraryDependencies <+= sbtVersion(v => v match {
  case "0.11.0" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.0-0.2.8"
  case "0.11.1" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.1-0.2.10"
  case "0.11.2" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.2-0.2.11"
  case "0.11.3" => "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.11.3-0.2.11.1"
  case x if (x.startsWith("0.12")) =>
    "com.github.siasia" %% "xsbt-web-plugin" % "0.12.0-0.2.11.1"
})

resolvers += "Jawsy.fi M2 releases" at "http://oss.jawsy.fi/maven2/releases"

addSbtPlugin("fi.jawsy.sbtplugins" %% "sbt-jrebel-plugin" % "0.9.0")
```

**Here is the global plugins file, which should be in ~/.sbt/plugins/plugins.sbt** If you put stuff here, it will be loaded into all your SBT projects, system wide. This only stands for your machine of course.

```
resolvers += Classpaths.typesafeResolver

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0")

resolvers += "jgit-repo" at "http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/maven"

addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-git" % "0.5.0")

addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.2.0")

resolvers += "Jawsy.fi M2 releases" at "http://oss.jawsy.fi/maven2/releases"

addSbtPlugin("fi.jawsy.sbtplugins" %% "sbt-jrebel-plugin" % "0.9.0")
```

Comment: For working with this project in eclipse, should i configure anything in eclipse other than the  addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0") in plugins.sbt.

Comment: i have already installed Scala 2.10 in my eclipse. but now also it is not working. can i copy paste your build.sbt and run?

Comment: but in this plugins.sbt, nothing can be find like addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "2.1.0") for eclipse. it is not mandatory in the file or not.?

Comment: while project loading in the cmd by giving the command sbt it is showing as "project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, (i)gnore"

Comment: yes am using windows..error is showing in command prompt in   [1]: http://download.scala-ide.org/sdk/e37/scala210/dev/site/ line of project/plugins.sbt